# What is the best way/tool to convert Bulk BMP images to .pk and .raw images on Linux?

Tags: linux, image-processing, file-conversion

I am working on a project that involves converting .bmp to .pk and .raw files(for 1 bmp file there will be one pk and 1 raw files). Can anyone suggest a tool or process for conversion and the tool should be able to handle around 1.5M bmp images and I am working on a linux server.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a tool recommendation site.

Comment: I agree its not tool recommendation site, but i also asked for a process that can be utilized for this issue